# Why do Greenhouse Gases absorb heavily in certain wavelengths?

Tags: thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation, earth, gas, absorption

What molecular properties make greenhouse gases absorb and reemit primarily IR radiation? That is, why are CO2, H2O and NO2 all greenhouse gases (GHGs), but others (such as helium and neon) aren't?

Furthermore, is there a mathematical approach to determining the distribution of absorption of a certain chemical, based on its molecular bonds and structure?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: What you are asking about is squarely in the field of infrared spectroscopy. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared_spectroscopy for a very brief introduction. There are many, many books on the topic.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, a central atom connected to multiple others gives a greenhouse gas, because it results in the kinetic degrees of freedom discussed in @CharlesTucker3's answer. There are exceptions, though: for example, sulphur dioxide is [if anything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratospheric_aerosol_injection#Materials) an _anti_ GHG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CO2, H2O etc. are molecules that have vibrational and rotational states that can be excited due to they inner structure (they consist of several atoms bound together). Vibrational and rotational transitions have lower energy than electronic transitions that you need to excite in atoms like helium. Thus, greenhouse gases can absorb longer wavelengths, i.e. IR radiation.

Comment: To visualize this think of a flute that due to its material properties resonates with some frequincies. These molecules also resonate at certain frequincies and are therefore able to absorb them.